# discord bot не выполняет команды

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

ВОПРОС ПО ПОВОДУ ДИСКОРД БОТА. вот как объединить(если так можно выразиться) @bot.command() и @bot.event
я хочу чтобы бот  реагировал на и на обычные сообщения и на команды

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'123')
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  print(f'Message by {message.author}: {message.content}')
bot.run(token)
```

Comment: [**Бот игнорирует команды**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/problems/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B.md)

Answer (score 3):

Ваш бот не отвечает на сообщения, так как дальше on_message он не может проверить команды.
Добавьте после print(..)
Строку

```
await bot.process_commands(ctx)
```

Полный код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    print(f'Message by {ctx.author}: {ctx.content}')

    await bot.process_commands(ctx)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Это тестовая команда.')

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, не могли бы вы отметить его галочкой?